# bind function and this in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanted to implement a simple context binding but it doesn't work in TypeScript.
Here is my piece of code:

```
class Engine {
    // some code...

    spriteController(sprite: Sprite, callbackfn: (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => void) {
        callbackfn.bind(new SpriteController(sprite), [this._ctx]);
    }

    // code again ...
}
```

If I want to use spriteController method in another file like this:

```
engine.spriteController(sprite, function(ctx) {
    this.moveRight() // access to the spriteController class
})
```

I want to be able to use the SpriteController class within the callback. 
 
In JS, the first argument (within the bind() call) bind 'this' to the given object. But in TypeScript, functions created from function.bind are always preserve 'this'. 
How to achieve this in TypeScript?

Comment: Could you please explain with another words what are you trying to archieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When binding, it is returning the bound function, you have to update your variable width `callbackfn = callbackfn.bind(...)`:

[Documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
class Engine {
    spriteController(sprite: Sprite, callbackfn: (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => void) {
        let callbackfnBinded = callbackfn.bind(new SpriteController(sprite), [this._ctx])
        callbackfnBinded()
    }
}
```

JavaScript here:

```js
var Sprite = (function () {
    function Sprite(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return Sprite;
})();
var SpriteController = (function () {
    function SpriteController(sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }
    return SpriteController;
})();
var Engine = (function () {
    function Engine() {
    }
    Engine.prototype.spriteController = function (sprite, callbackfn) {
        callbackfn = callbackfn.bind(new SpriteController(sprite), [this._ctx])
        callbackfn()
    };
    return Engine;
})();
var e = new Engine();
var s = new Sprite("test");
var cb = function (ctx) {
    alert(this.sprite.name);
};
e.spriteController(s, cb);
```

Comment: I try, but it does not work. I read on the documentation that functions created from function.bind are always preserve 'this'...

Comment: After reading again, I must admit that I'm not sure if I understood your answer correctly

Comment: @SebBizeul can you re-explain your question diffrently?

Comment: OK sorry! Method spriteController is in Engine class. When I will use it in a different part of my program, I want to set 'this' on the SpriteController class. That's why I'm calling 'bind(new SpriteController)'. But actually it does not work

Comment: @SebBizeul The answer might not totaly have been what you are looking for, I updated it. Tell me if its ok

Comment: With the last answer, compiler complains about 'callbackfn()' It says: supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. I fixed with callbackfn(this._ctx). I am right?

Comment: Yes, or just assign it to a new Variable, so TypeScript does not moan for the (not realy) missing argument - updated

Comment: Ok it works great, thank you! But I have a problem with the _ctx object. A call to ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100); within the callback gives me an error: ctx.clearRect is not a function. It's weird...

Comment: Well thats a new Problem/Question, maybe you can post the relevant code in a new question, and link it here so I can have a look at it? You could also use console.log(ctx) at the place where you use the fillRect - or is it clearRect? :D